# ASP.net Update pannel and trigger

Tags: asp.net-ajax

My page contains drop down list, buttons, datagridview and all these have events . Is add all these events under the `<trigger>` for `<updatepannel>`?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrongly understanding your question, there's no need of registering child update panel control's events.

You just need to register triggers for such controls that should provoke a partial or full postback outside the update panel (there're other situations where you'll need to do for some reasons to the inner ones).

I hope this was helpful for you :)

Comment: ok .. let me know that the controls like dropdownlist inside the updatepannel put event in trigger